How to debug Scrapy in VS Code?
The problem is that I can't debug Scrapy crawlers in VS Code. The problem is that always when I start debugging it breaks on one of my imports. Of course, I played a lot with that import in order to fix it, but it didn't helped. I also tried with venv and without venv, but it doesn't helped.
Anyone faced the same issue?
Here is the error

It looks like your scrapy_project folder is a package because you have a init.py file present in it. The error is most likely due to wrong import and with path. Try to cplay with paths and see if it resolve the error. For example, you can try from .items import Garment

Navigate to the project's directory.

I don't have experience with Scrapy, but if this happens in debug mode only and it run's ok otherwise (from CLI), than most likely there is problem with your Python paths.
Do you use Python virtual environment?

I tried with venv and without it. It is the same.

Does it work from CLI?

This was usually caused by incorrect python interpreter.
You could use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose your python interperter.
If it doesn't work, you could set python in your launch.json.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_python

The full path that points to the Python interpreter to be used for
debugging.
If not specified, this setting defaults to the interpreter selected
for your workspace, which is equivalent to using the value
${command:python.interpreterPath}. To use a different interpreter,
specify its path instead in the python property of a debug
configuration.
Alternately, you can use a custom environment variable that's defined
on each platform to contain the full path to the Python interpreter to
use, so that no other folder paths are needed.
If you need to pass arguments to the Python interpreter, you can use
the pythonArgs property.


Not sure if this will solve your problem but you should try to re-initialize the Scrapy project.
scrapy startproject <project_name>

then try importing
from items import Garment

Also, it looks like something in your venv was modified. If you modified that folder at all it's going to cause all your imports to behave differently.
Hope this helps!
